# How assert if String is present in a List of Strings?

Tags: java, junit, assert

How would I create a junit test that checks if given String is present in List of String?

I was thinking using `contains` but not sure if I am on the right path or not.

Comment: You have the solution. Edit your Question to express your reservations or concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like that (there are other ways):

```
@Test
public void testContains() {
    var list = List.of("a", "b", "c");
    assertTrue(list.contains("a"));
}
```